# Simple regex problem!

Tags: regex, numbers, preg-replace, letter

I want to remove everything from a string except numbers, letters, _ (underscore) and : (colon)

It's PREG and I've only come across #\W#, but it removes the : (colon).

Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: More like "I don't know anything about regex". In which case you better learn it (at least the basics, which are sufficient for this).

Comment: Like delnan said you should just look up regular expressions.

Comment: Hi, I asked for help, not to be told to learn it.

Comment: Not sure why the harsh comments and downvote - it's a perfectly valid question, and it shows the OP did try to learn and made an attempt. The question is complete, and states the problem very clearly. Welcome to stack overflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`[^\w:]+` - Remove anything that isn't (`[^...]`) a letter, digit, underscore (`\w`) or colon (`:`).

Sample code:

```
$ptn = "/[^\w:]+/";
$str = "Hello~~~ World+++: 123";
echo preg_replace($ptn, "", $str);
```

Outputs: `HelloWorld:123`

Comment: Kobi, thanks for your answer but it doesn't seem to work.

I'm using PHP and it gave me the following error: Warning: preg_replace() [function.preg-replace]: Unknown modifier '+' in D:\Servers\Web\public_html\index.php on line 17

Comment: @Synergy - I'm not sure what is your problem, perhaps you can post some of your code? I've updated the answer with a sample. In any case, it should work exactly the same without the `+`.